# Transitive Dependency: Using Elasticsearch Rest High Client problem in AEM

Tags: maven, elasticsearch, osgi, aem, elasticsearch-api

I am trying to use [Java High Level Rest Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.4/java-rest-high.html) in **Adobe Experience Manager** to finish project of **comparison between Lucene, Solr and Elasticsearch search engines**.

I am having some problems with **elasticsearh implementation**.
Here is the code:

- Dependency in the parent pom.xml (the same is defined in core pom.xml)

  ```
  <!-- Elasticseach dependencies -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
      <version>7.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- The only line of code that I am using that is from dependencies above

  ```
  try (RestHighLevelClient client = new 
  RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(server, port, 
  protocol),
    new HttpHost(server, secondPort, protocol)));)
  {

  }
  catch (ElasticsearchException e)
  {
      LOG.error("Exception: " + e);
  }
  ```

> protocol = "http", server = "localhost", port = 9200, secondPort =
>   9201

- Error

[image]

- Dependencies from IntelliJ

[image]

I know that there is usually problem with dependencies versions, but all are **7.4.0** in this case. Also elasticsearch 7.4.0v is running locally on 3 nodes.

This project is done on **We.Retail** project so it is easy to replicate. Also all the code with this error is available here:
https://github.com/tadijam64/search-engines-comparison-on-we-retail/tree/elasticsearch-integration
AEM 6.4v.

Any info or idea is appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I tried with adding the following to embed these dependencies externally since they are not OSGi dependencies:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Embed-Dependency>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.solr-solrj, log4j, noggit, zookeeper,
                            elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client
                        </Embed-Dependency>
                        <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                        <Embed-Directory>OSGI-INF/lib</Embed-Directory>
                        <Export-Package>we.retail.core.model*</Export-Package>
                        <Import-Package>
                            *;resolution:=optional
                        </Import-Package>
                        <Private-Package>we.retail.core*</Private-Package>
                        <Sling-Model-Packages>
                            we.retail.core.model
                        </Sling-Model-Packages>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

The error remains. I also tried adding it to the "export-package", but nothing helps.

And by [Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.4/java-rest-high-getting-started-maven.html), all I need to use Elasticsearch is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

but then **NoClassDefFoundErrors** occurs. It seems like a problem with transitive dependencies maybe. Not sure, but any idea is appreciated.

Some other suggestions can be found here: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2653586

**I have also tried adding it's transitive dependencies like org.elasticsearch and org.elasticsearch.client, but it does not work. The same error, just other class.**

AEM version 6.4, Java version: jdk1.8.0_191.jdk

Comment: In AEM System Console bundles, do you see any dependency related to elastic search?

Comment: Only under manifest headers and bundle classpath, should it be elsewhere as well?

Comment: I think manifest would have some import entries etc. The actual dependency is not present. I think elastic search is not provided by AEM, probably that's why you are getting Class Not Found exception. Dependency needs to be [Embedded or separately installed as OSGi bundle](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2323638)

Comment: Tried that, installed ES rest high level client and org.elasticsearch dependencies manually and added as dependencies, but now I have similar: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/common/xcontent/DeprecationHandler"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So my guess was right, transitive dependencies were not included altho `<Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>` exists.

The following is necessary when running **elasticsearch** as a search engine on **AEM** the problem:

- I have added all **transitive dependencies** in pom.xml (versions are defined in parent/pom.xml):

  ```
    <!-- Elasticsearch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-x-content</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>rank-eval-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-imaging</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>lang-mustache-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
  ```

It is important to add all **third-party dependencies** as <**Embed-Dependency**> inside **maven-bundle-plugin** like this:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
            <instructions>
                <Embed-Dependency>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.solr-solrj, noggit,
                    elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client,
                    elasticsearch,
                    elasticsearch-rest-client,
                    elasticsearch-x-content,
                    elasticsearch-core,
                    rank-eval-client,
                    lang-mustache-client,
                    httpasyncclient;
                </Embed-Dependency>
                <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                <Embed-Directory>OSGI-INF/lib</Embed-Directory>
                <Export-Package>we.retail.core.model*</Export-Package>
                <Import-Package>
                    *;resolution:=optional
                </Import-Package>
                <Private-Package>
                    we.retail.core*
                </Private-Package>
                <Sling-Model-Packages>
                    we.retail.core.model
                </Sling-Model-Packages>
                <_fixupmessages>"Classes found in the wrong directory";is:=warning</_fixupmessages>
            </instructions>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

> Important to notice:
>
> - All third-party dependencies (the ones outside of OSGi) must be included in the "Embed-Dependency"
> - "Embed-Transitive" must be set to true to include transitive dependencies
> - "Import-Package" must include "*;resolution:=optional" to exclude all dependencies that could not be resolved so that the program can run
>   normally
> - For some reason, there was an error in compile time when "elasticsearch" dependency was added which is not important for this
>   task, so I've decided to ignore it this way:

```
<_fixupmessages>"Classes found in the wrong directory";is:=warning</_fixupmessages>
```

Though challenging, I finally resolved it. There are many similar or the same problems on Google, so I hope this will help someone. Thanks to everyone that tried to help.